# How to achive key logger using key press event in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want key logger application to keep it running in background. while all the key strokes should get recorded in some text file or in any other control from where it can be retrieved.

Comment: Are you working for NNSSAA ?

Comment: Are you trying to steal someone's online game account at public internet shop?

Comment: Are you trying to catch your wife spending credit card funds on non-returnable non-turn-uppable unicorns?

Comment: Most people probably aren't going to help you with this because of the topic.  They also aren't going to help because this is a very general question that comes across as 'I want this, do it for me'.  This site is to help with **specific** problems that you can demonstrate what you have already tried and why it isn't working.

Comment: `I want key logger [...]` What a coincidence, me too. And then I want to use it to find out the US President's accounts and passwords, so I get full access to all kinds of weaponry. It's going to be fun! Btw. what's your question anyways?

Comment: Friends! I got what I was searching for, then why there was a need to put it on hold?

Comment: https://github.com/fabriciorissetto/KeystrokeAPI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got my keylogger from http://cskeylogger.codeplex.com/. Thanks for the wonderful suggestions.